# Django aggregate by field with no related name

Tags: django

Given these models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Reward(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
```

I am trying to obtain a QuerySet that contains something similar:

```
| user    | reward__count |
| 1       | 103           |
| 2       | 50            |
| 3       | 67            |
```

[Conventional wisdom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/) would recommend a query looking like

```
User.objects\
    .annotate(reward__count=Count('reward_set'))\
    .values_list('user', 'reward__count')
```

Unfortunately, because the related name is `+`, neither `reward_set` nor `rewards` (if I could name it) would qualify as a valid parameter for `Count()`. Given this situation, is there truly no way other than a python for loop to obtain the desired QuerySet?

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    user_rewards = Reward.objects.filter(user=user).count()
    # Store (user.pk, user_rewards) somewhere.
```

Comment: So why don't you allow it to set a related name?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if they're part of a library (and not the hip kind you find on github, but an semi-internal one no one dare touches), what would you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to obtain a QuerySet that contains something similar:
>
> ```
> | user    | reward__count |
> | 1       | 103           |
> | 2       | 50            |
> | 3       | 67            |
> ```

This you can do, by using [aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values) on the `Reward` objects:

```
# Fetch a list of rewards, grouped by
rewards = Reward.objects.values('user').annotate(Count('id')).order_by()
```

This will give you a list like this:

```
[
    {'user': 1, 'id__count': 103}, 
    {'user': 2, 'id__count': 50}, 
    {'user': 3, 'id__count': 67},
    ...
]
```

Where `user` is the user ID, and `id__count` is the number of rewards associated with that user.

Comment: good idea. what do you think of mine? (sneaked in a link to one of my docs pages as well)

Comment: Clever (and legit) use of values()! Thanks a lot, both of you.

Answer (score 4):

@solarissmoke has posted a good answer which I upvoted, I would like to propose an alternative? an [unmanaged model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed).

Create an unmanaged model that points to the same table as the one in the untouchable library app.

```
class RewardOnSteroids(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='pick something')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'original table name'
```

Comment: As far as documentation goes, [here is a link to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed). (I am still not convinced about SO documentation...)